# Text parsing in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have few Files containing email conversations for job posting . I want to extract job title,location and duration from its subject line,but having hard time figuring out how I can do that.
here are few examples of subject lines.

> Subject: Looking for software developer : Cranbury New Jersey - 12 MOnths Contract
>
> Subject:Immediate requirement for Math teacher in Warsaw IN for Full Time.
>
> Subject:AP FICO Consultant-----North Carolina

Comment: How do you do that?  You write code.  If you run into specific problems writing the code, then ask questions here, but "how can I solve [this big problem] is not an appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use regex to accurately filter the dataset into the categories you need if the dataset has no clear format like the example you posted

Answer (score 1):

You would need to dive deeper and figure out how to analyze those subject lines for the keywords you are looking for. You would need to cross-reference location names, job titles and filter out the fluff words and characters.

If you really wanted to get into this, you should look into [Deep Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) and [Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) to process those subject lines to extract the relevant information. Only when you are able to do this (or similar) will you be able to categorize your emails and highlight those keywords for sorting/organizing.

This is not an easy process, and if you pursue it, good luck!